# How can I convert this string "07/10/2017 18:30 PM" to JavaScript Date type

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, date-comparison

I am trying to read all dates in a table and see if those dates are old dates than current date time and if those are old dates then highlight those dates with some color.

Here is my Javascript code

```
$(".ticket-gird-td-duedate").each(function(i, e) {
        debugger;
        var dueDateAsString = $(e).text();
        console.log(dueDateAsString);  
        var dueDate = new Date(dueDateAsString);
        var currentdate = new Date();
        if (dueDate < currentdate) {
            //mark date in red color
            console.log("I need to change color for this date as this is past date" + dueDate);
        }
    });
```

Problem here is `dueDateAsString` comes as `"07/10/2017 18:30 PM"`

And when I am doing

```
new Date("07/10/2017 18:30 PM")
```

it fails with invalid date error

> Invalid Date

How can I convert my string date to Javascript date and proceed to compare it with current date?

Comment: no  Michal Hainc i need this result in javascript.

Comment: You can wrap `check` with `new Date()`, like this: `var check = new Date(todayDate.setDate(todayDate.getDate() - 5));`

Comment: Uh, where does your code have a date string?

Comment: @Dinesh I understand reluctance to bring in a big honkin library like moment for something that seems like it should be simple, but the only cross browser datestring format supported is [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). For your datestring you'll have to use moment or parse it out into integer values to feed to the date constructor by hand.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't a valid date, as you either have 24hr format or AM|PM 12hr format.

This works:

```
new Date('07/10/2017 18:30'); // No 'PM' after the 24hr time
```

Also note that JS dates are mutable, so `todayDate` and `check` will hold the same date value, but `check` will be a number.

Comment: Does this work in all browsers? IIRC only ISO 8601 is universally supported.

Comment: @JaredSmith It works in Chrome, Safari, FireFox, Edge and current IE. I'm not sure how far back though as even the latest IE is garbage. The ISO format is much better, as this date is ambiguous between cultures (America, and hence JS, defaults to mm/dd/yyyy while everybody else does dd/mm/yyyy).

Comment: Given IE's vanishing market share one could be forgiven for not caring in the slightest. Nice answer, simple.

Answer (score 0):

You call this one first

```
todayDate.setDate(todayDate.getDate() - 5);
```

It will update todayDate to 5 days ago. Then you just assign it to check or you todayDate further.

```
var check = todayDate;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com) library (yet another terrific way to achieve date parsing).

> **Moment.Js** library is freely available. You can use either a minified or full version of this library as you require. In this
>   library all the operations are performed on a moment object so the
>   date or time is stored in this library as a moment object only. So
>   this moment object is the core of this entire library. You can find
>   this library at [Moment.js site's home page](https://momentjs.com).

Add `momentjs` library reference into your project - `https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js`

updated code with moment.js would be:

```
var todayDate = new moment().format("MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss a");
var yesterday = todayDate.toLocaleString();
var check = moment(todayDate, "MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss a").add('days', -5);    
alert("Your Old Date is- " + todayDate);
alert(check);
alert("Your Old Date is- " + yesterday);
```

[JavaScript fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1919onn5/2/)